# How to use xls:if to populate a table dependent upon the existence of a node

Tags: xslt

I am brand new to xslt and I am trying to create an output table in html from an xlm file.  I am stuck on the following requirement:  I need to pull the home address if it exists, and if it doesn't I need to use the work address.  I am working on the code to check for and insert the home Address_Line_1 into my table.  Here is the xml I am working with:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Workers_Response wd:version="v17" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
       <wd:Request_Criteria>
        <wd:Organization_Reference wd:Descriptor="MMM Money Market Mansion (Marcia Menos)">
           <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f10da305867044b8a30c67671e4034c1</wd:ID>
           <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">SUPERVISORY_ORGANIZATION-1-219</wd:ID>
        </wd:Organization_Reference>
     </wd:Request_Criteria>
     <wd:Response_Results>
        <wd:Total_Results>5</wd:Total_Results>
        <wd:Total_Pages>1</wd:Total_Pages>
        <wd:Page_Results>5</wd:Page_Results>
        <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
     </wd:Response_Results>
     <wd:Response_Data>
        <wd:Worker>
           <wd:Worker_Reference wd:Descriptor="Gabriel Bezerra">
              <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1efbe4be1e764a4d8dd205ee6550cafb</wd:ID>
              <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">21305</wd:ID>
           </wd:Worker_Reference>
           <wd:Worker_Data>
              <wd:Worker_ID>21305</wd:Worker_ID>
              <wd:User_ID>gbezerra</wd:User_ID>
              <wd:Personal_Data>
                 <wd:Name_Data>
                    <wd:Legal_Name_Data>
                       <wd:Name_Detail_Data wd:Formatted_Name="Gabriel Bezerra" wd:Reporting_Name="Bezerra, Gabriel">
                          <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="Brazil">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1a29bb1357b240ab99a2fa755cc87c0e</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">BR</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">BRA</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">76</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Country_Reference>
                          <wd:First_Name>Gabriel</wd:First_Name>
                          <wd:Last_Name>Bezerra</wd:Last_Name>
                       </wd:Name_Detail_Data>
                    </wd:Legal_Name_Data>
                    <wd:Preferred_Name_Data>
                       <wd:Name_Detail_Data wd:Formatted_Name="Gabriel Bezerra" wd:Reporting_Name="Bezerra, Gabriel">
                          <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="Brazil">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1a29bb1357b240ab99a2fa755cc87c0e</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">BR</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">BRA</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">76</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Country_Reference>
                          <wd:First_Name>Gabriel</wd:First_Name>
                          <wd:Last_Name>Bezerra</wd:Last_Name>
                       </wd:Name_Detail_Data>
                    </wd:Preferred_Name_Data>
                 </wd:Name_Data>
                 <wd:Gender_Reference wd:Descriptor="Male">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d3afbf8074e549ffb070962128e1105a</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">Male</wd:ID>
                 </wd:Gender_Reference>
                 <wd:Birth_Date>1980-08-13-07:00</wd:Birth_Date>
                 <wd:Marital_Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="Single (United States of America)">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0c855e50cb12452487de0caf7f262d4f</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Marital_Status_ID">Single_USA</wd:ID>
                 </wd:Marital_Status_Reference>
                 <wd:Disability_Reference wd:Descriptor="Hearing Impairment (United States of America)">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">a59abdaa91474e26a4fe3c55ec3775ef</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Disability_ID">Hearing_Impairment_USA</wd:ID>
                 </wd:Disability_Reference>
                 <wd:Hispanic_or_Latino>0</wd:Hispanic_or_Latino>
                 <wd:Citizenship_Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="Citizen (United States of America)">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2ec46eb7edcc4d5aa97af54147204e0e</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Citizenship_Status_Code">USA_Citizen</wd:ID>
                 </wd:Citizenship_Status_Reference>
                 <wd:Military_Service_Data>
                    <wd:Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="0 - Inactive (United States of America)">
                       <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dee05ff9af5341f08c5b0cc651d86f9b</wd:ID>
                       <wd:ID wd:type="Military_Status_ID">Inactive_USA</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Status_Reference>
                    <wd:Discharge_Date>2012-08-01-07:00</wd:Discharge_Date>
                 </wd:Military_Service_Data>
                 <wd:Identification_Data>
                    <wd:National_ID>
                       <wd:National_ID_Reference wd:Descriptor="001-33-3450 (USA-SSN)">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">af5e69b72e2a404c8cd8c7383302f036</wd:ID>
                       </wd:National_ID_Reference>
                       <wd:National_ID_Data>
                          <wd:ID>001333450</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID_Type_Reference wd:Descriptor="Social Security Number (SSN)">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">93636994cfe84825a1daaa933cbba7e7</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="National_ID_Type_Code">USA-SSN</wd:ID>
                          </wd:ID_Type_Reference>
                          <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="United States of America">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc33aa3152ec42d4995f4791a106ed09</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">US</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">USA</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">840</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Country_Reference>
                          <wd:Verification_Date>2012-08-13-07:00</wd:Verification_Date>
                       </wd:National_ID_Data>
                    </wd:National_ID>
                 </wd:Identification_Data>
                 <wd:Contact_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="2000-01-01-08:00" wd:Address_Format_Type="Extended" wd:Formatted_Address="Av Cmte Júlio Moura, 900&amp;#xa;Barra de Tijuca&amp;#xa;Rio de Janeiro- RJ&amp;#xa;22621-252&amp;#xa;Brazil" wd:Defaulted_Business_Site_Address="0">
                       <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="Brazil">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1a29bb1357b240ab99a2fa755cc87c0e</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">BR</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">BRA</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">76</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Reference>
                       <wd:Last_Modified>2009-06-06T20:07:49.246-07:00</wd:Last_Modified>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1" wd:Descriptor="Street Name">Av Cmte Júlio Moura</wd:Address_Line_Data>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_3" wd:Descriptor="House Number">900</wd:Address_Line_Data>
                       <wd:Municipality>Rio de Janeiro</wd:Municipality>
                       <wd:Submunicipality_Data>Barra de Tijuca</wd:Submunicipality_Data>
                       <wd:Country_Region_Reference wd:Descriptor="Rio de Janeiro">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e88c3d7cdb2b4a8b8120ede0b16e2186</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="Country_Region_ID">BRA-RJ</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Region_Reference>
                       <wd:Postal_Code>22621-252</wd:Postal_Code>
                       <wd:Usage_Data wd:Public="0">
                          <wd:Type_Data wd:Primary="1">
                             <wd:Type_Reference wd:Descriptor="Home">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">836cf00ef5974ac08b786079866c946f</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Type_ID">HOME</wd:ID>
                             </wd:Type_Reference>
                          </wd:Type_Data>
                          <wd:Use_For_Reference wd:Descriptor="Street Address">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f785430145674364a613cd56086942c4</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">STREET</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Use_For_Reference>
                          <wd:Use_For_Reference wd:Descriptor="Mailing">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9385649a0c4b4ddea7fb0d823c2f1bcd</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">MAILING</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Use_For_Reference>
                       </wd:Usage_Data>
                    </wd:Address_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="2000-01-01-08:00" wd:Address_Format_Type="Basic" wd:Formatted_Address="3755 Peachtree Road NE&amp;#xa;Atlanta, GA 30305&amp;#xa;United States of America" wd:Defaulted_Business_Site_Address="1">
                       <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="United States of America">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc33aa3152ec42d4995f4791a106ed09</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">US</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">USA</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">840</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Reference>
                       <wd:Last_Modified>2011-06-20T13:54:02.466-07:00</wd:Last_Modified>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1" wd:Descriptor="Address Line 1">3755 Peachtree Road NE</wd:Address_Line_Data>
                       <wd:Municipality>Atlanta</wd:Municipality>
                       <wd:Country_Region_Reference wd:Descriptor="Georgia">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dec8eabbb13d45bdb159b8e25d896110</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="Country_Region_ID">USA-GA</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Region_Reference>
                       <wd:Postal_Code>30305</wd:Postal_Code>
```

And here is the portion on the xslt that I am having trouble with.  It does not give me any error codes, but it simply does nothing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Workers_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker/wd:Worker_Data">
    <tr>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_ID"/></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select= "wd:Personal_Data/wd:Name_Data/wd:Legal_Name_Data/wd:Name_Detail_Data/wd:Last_Name"/></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select= "wd:Personal_Data/wd:Name_Data/wd:Legal_Name_Data/wd:Name_Detail_Data/wd:First_Name"/></td> 
       <td><xsl:if test = "wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type = ADDRESS_LINE_1]"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type = ADDRESS_LINE_1]"/></xsl:if></td>
```

The first three columns populate just fine, but the fourth column with the if statement does nothing. Per the prior advice received, I eliminated the stray "/" at the beginning of the path in the xsl:if staatement, but it still does nothing.   Any ideas?  I appreciate the assistance, thanks in advance, and thanks who those who have already commented!

Comment: For starters you have a stray leading `/` in front of the `wd:Personal_Data` in those last xpaths, removing that should help,

Comment: Could you give us an example of input XML with and without the home address? The sample you've given gives no indication of how to distinguish one from the other. Also, could you give us a somewhat more complete view of what your XSLT looks like so we can see where this part fits in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the XSLT snippet you have shown is the use of the `/` symbol at the start of the xpath expression:

```
<xsl:if test = "/wd:Personal_Data/....
```

By beginning the xpath expression with this forward slash, this means it is an absolute expression, starting right back at the top-level document element. You just want a relative expression here, relative to the current **wd:Worker_Data** element

```
<xsl:if test = "wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type = ADDRESS_LINE_1]">
```